# Jquery remove a line with line break from a paragraph

Tags: jquery, replace, newline

I need help on this... I have a long paragraph with numbered lines. I need to remove a line with it's linebreak.

E.g

```
1|ncubicx|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncubicx.com
2|asd|fdf
3|asd|asd
4|as|asd
5|sds|sds
6|asa|asa
7|asd|fdf
8|google|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
9|flipkart|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2F
10|amazon|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.in
```

The above one is contained in a variable `str`. I want to remove the 2nd entry with jQuery.
So that the result becomes like this...

```
1|ncubicx|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncubicx.com
3|asd|asd
4|as|asd
5|sds|sds
6|asa|asa
7|asd|fdf
8|google|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
9|flipkart|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2F
```

10|amazon|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.in

But when I use:

```
oldrep="2|asd|fdf";    
var res = str.replace(oldrep, "");
```

I get a blank line in between like below...

```
1|ncubicx|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncubicx.com

3|asd|asd
4|as|asd
5|sds|sds
6|asa|asa
7|asd|fdf
8|google|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
9|flipkart|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2F
10|amazon|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.in
```

I need to remove the whole line...
How to do it? Any help is appreciated...

Comment: try to add `oldrep="2|asd|fdf\r\n"; `  if this gives syntax error then change  single slash with double

Comment: not sure...try after adding '\n' in oldrep variable

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = `1|ncubicx|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncubicx.com
2|asd|fdf
3|asd|asd
4|as|asd
5|sds|sds
6|asa|asa
7|asd|fdf
8|google|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
9|flipkart|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2F
10|amazon|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.in`;

console.log(x.replace("2|asd|fdf\n", ""));
```

Will do it..

**Note** `` var x = `...` `` is a way of declaring a multiline string.

[Play it here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7n09Lkn/)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to split the lines to a array and remove the line and join it back

```
var str = `1|ncubicx|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncubicx.com
2|asd|fdf
3|asd|asd
4|as|asd
5|sds|sds
6|asa|asa
7|asd|fdf
8|google|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com
9|flipkart|http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flipkart.com%2F
10|amazon|https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.co.in`;

 var strArray = str.split('\n');
 strArray.splice(1, 1);
 var newStr = strArray.join('\n');
```

Comment: Array operations are complicated and complex.. You can do it in `O(n)` using regex match.

Comment: When you have to point to a line number it is better to use arrays.

Comment: @void Thanks for your inputs, for me arrays are very simple to understand in this case.